# Practice for dividing properly work between Spring Controllers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to web development so please bear with my misunderstandings .

Let's have the following example :

A user wants to perform these operations : *login, logout, add 2 numbers, write a comment.*

From my current knowledge I would create 4 Controller classes like :

`loginController,logoutController, ArithmethicController, TextController.`

In these controllers I would to then all the required mappings but : 
the things like really *adding 2 numbers, write comments...*  must be done by other classes like `AdditionClass, WriteTextToSourceClass, UserAuthClass` right ?

Furthermore, the `AdditionClass, WriteTextToSourceClass, UserAuthClass` should extend the HttpServlet probably.

What bugs me, is that I don't know where this `Servlet` thing comes into play and what is it really used/responsible for if I already divided the work between Controllers, so what work is left for my servlets here ?

Comment: They should not extend servlet. The controllers are the "servlets" (actually Spring MVC provides the servlet, with controllers at entry points.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring uses the `Dispatcher Servlet` that you define in `web.xml`. Thanks to this you can focus on just creating the controllers. `@Controller` means that Spring will find your mappings.
In your example with just the 4 methods it seems to be overkill to have more than one controller. However in Java generally it is good practice to divide tasks as OO as possible of course. The actual work to be done that you mention usually goes in `@Service` classes and not extend Servlet. So forget about creating your own Servlets and just work with Controllers, Services and Daos (for CRUD operations, the model i.e).

in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

These tutorials really helped me get started: https://www.gontu.org/spring-framework-tutorials/